# Is Latex useful for custom formatting?

Tags: fonts, color

This is what I want:

1. When I type something between ``, it should turn bold and green.
2. When I type Q:, the text following it till it meets a ? should turn italics and blue.

Can this kind of stuff be achieved through Latex?
If yes, then please guide by pointing to relevant documents of Latex.

In reply to this comment: [Is Latex useful for custom formatting?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407124/is-latex-useful-for-custom-formatting#comment1015333_407124)

> What is your actual goal? Do you want to create an application that generates a PDF or do you want to write LaTeX plus these new features?

My goal is to type the following content with the shown formatting and colors in a modifiable document:
[image]

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401767/134144

Comment: Do you use pdfLaTeX? Is switching to LuaLaTeX an option for you? Please also provide more details about your formatting needs. E.g. should just the material between the quotation marks be rendered in green and bold, or should this also pertain to the quotation marks? Should the quotation marks be shown? For the `Q: ... ?` strings: should `Q` and `?`  be rendered in blue and italics as well?

Comment: @Mico not using anything related to latex as of now.

Comment: What is your actual goal? Do you want to create an application that generates a PDF or do you want to write LaTeX plus these new features?

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: @PålGD please see the edit.

Comment: I think that some kind of [markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) language will be more useful for this kind of application. I do not know how to customize it (probably [some `css` magic](http://mixu.net/markdown-styles/) )...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution.

[image]

This solution takes a preprocessor approach. Lua has several very powerful and flexible pattern-matching functions. The Lua function `make_replacements` performs two pattern-matching-and-substitution operations on all input material, *before* TeX even begins its "regular" processing.

---

*Addendum* to incorporate the additional information provided by the OP regarding his/her typesetting objectives:

LaTeX is very well suited to handle such typesetting needs. I suggest you (a) define the following macro in the preamble

```
\newcommand\QQ[1]{\par\noindent Q: {\itshape\textcolor{green}{#1}}\par}
```

and then write something like

```
\QQ{What is a pointer?}
```

or

```
\QQ{Where are expressions, constants stored if not in memory?}
```

in the body of the text. Similarly, you'd provide an `\AA` macro that provides the basic formatting of the answers.

---

Here's the code that generates the screenshot shown above.

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,luacode}

%% Lua-side code
\begin{luacode}
```

```lua
function make_replacements ( s )
  s = string.gsub ( s , "Q:(.-)%?" , "Q: {\\itshape\\color{blue}%1}?" )
  s = string.gsub ( s , "``(.-)''" ,  "``{\\bfseries\\color{green}%1}''" )
  return s
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode}
%% TeX-side code
\AtBeginDocument{\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback ( 
  "process_input_buffer" , make_replacements , "make_replacements" )}}

\begin{document}
bla bla Q: Yes? bla bla ``No'' More bla bla
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution is much simpler than I thought, great! Does this slow down the compilation much?

Comment: Hey, can I paint all "n" green? This does not work, getting `undefined control sequence`: `s = string.gsub ( s , "n" , "{\\color{green} n }" )` ? What's wrong?

Comment: @KeksDose be careful what you ask for... `\AtBegi{\color{green} n }Docume{\color{green} n }t`

Comment: @KeksDose - The preprocessor-based approach proposed here should work fine with strings of the type mentioned in the OP's query. It's bound to break down -- see David Carlisle's example -- for more generic queries, such as "make every instance of the letter `n` green". If you want a solution to the more generic queries, please post a new query.

Comment: @KeksDose - Regarding your first question, about how much slower compilation may be: There are two separate things to consider: First, LuaTeX is more complex than pdfTeX, i.e., it can handle much more complicated things than pdfTeX can. A cost is that compilation under LuaTeX will almost invariably slower than the corresponding compilation under pdfTeX. Second, the overhead imposed by the two string.gsub search-and-replace directives is likely quite low, as nether of the string.gsub operation is all that complicated.

Comment: @Mico Thank you! I'll ask about painting all "n"s green. But not today.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I have zero experience in Latex. I wish to know that the code that you have written here is something that a user is expected to write himself? Or is there some software of Latex where the user would have to specify 'Q' and '``' and expect the software to generate the code which you have written?

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl - You're welcome. The Lua part in LuaLaTeX refers to Lua, the modern programming language that's derived from "C". LuaTeX is the most modern of the three main TeX engines, the other two being pdfTeX and XeTeX. One of several things I love about LuaLaTeX is that combines the best of (a) LaTeX and (b) Lua, with a straightforward interface between them (mostly via `\directlua` and the `luacode` package.) To answer your questions: I'm not aware of any software that would somehow "generate the code" which I wrote. Fortunately, it doesn't take much experience in Lua to get started.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the very cool solution.

Answer (score 29):

[image: a bang for a buck picture]I'd say wrong approach. What you ask needs low level programming in TeX internals. You'll see that in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401767/134144), as linked in a comment by leandriis.

You can have it as simple as here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\bang}[1]{\textcolor{green}{\textbf{`#1`}}}
\newcommand{\Q}[1]{\emph{\textcolor{blue}{Q#1?}}}


\begin{document}

Always keep things as simple as possible. A \bang{bang for a
  buck}. More \Q{ualifications are needed if you mess things up}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\`#1'`?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 No, please have a look at the question!

Comment: I think the question's asking for the conversion of `\`text\`` to green `text`, not `text` to green `\`text\``. See the image in the question.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Probably you are right. But it is so easy to change that for any user. Not worth to change the code here and upload a new screenshot.

Answer (score 21):

TeX (and therefore LaTeX) allows you to redefine its parsing settings. This way specific characters can be made "active", i.e. they work like macros then. Also it allows you to specify an argument *text* which is searched when expanding macros. This way you can implement things like "read everything to the next '?'". However, you need to use plainTeX macros (e.g. `\def` instead of `\newcommand`). The best reference is "The TeXBook" by Knuth, but there are others (e.g. "TeX by reference"). I'm also using `\@ifnextchar`, which is  provided by LaTeX, to look ahead. Such macros are listed in [`macros2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/macros2e). It uses plainTeX's `\futurelet` however.

Note that this is advanced stuff which may cause errors if used incorrectly. Better would be to add macros yourself around the content. An alternative would be a script which converts the text to LaTeX by scanning for the patterns you described and added LaTeX macros around it automatically.

Note when a space follows the `Q` it is removed. This is due to `\@ifnextchar`. Also, you can no longer use `Q` inside macro names. I'm getting an error at `\begin{document}` as some other package tries to use the `Q` in an macro argument there. Therefore I moved the code after it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\def\old@q{Q}

\catcode`\Q=\active

\def Q{%
    \@ifnextchar :{%
        \process@q
    }{%
        \old@q
    }%
}


\def\process@q :#1?{%
    {\color{blue}\itshape #1}%
}
\makeatother

\catcode`\`=\active

\long\def`#1`{{\color{green}\bfseries #1}}

Test `it` out

Q: test it?

AA Q AA

Quick test 

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

---

The blue italic quotes can be implemented very nicely using the `newverbs` package. Just define a new verb command and then attach it to a character as "short verb".

```
\usepackage{newverbs}
\newverbcommand{\qblueitalic}{\begingroup\color{blue}\itshape\qverbbeginquote}{\qverbendquote\endgroup}
\MakeSpecialShortVerb{\qblueitalic}{\`}
```

The `\qverbbeginquote` and `\qverbendquote` macros readd the normal quote characters as normal text.

Comment: Thanks for the effort to you too. I have zero experience in Latex. I wish to know that the code that you have written here is something that a user is expected to write himself? Or is there some software of Latex where the user would have to specify 'Q' and '``' and expect the software to generate the code which you have written?  Have asked the same thing to the other answerer too. Not sure if he would reply so I am asking this to you too.

Comment: @Aquarius_Girl: As I mentioned, this is advanced, programming stuff using TeX. Note that LaTeX is more or less a userinterface above TeX, which defines a lot of often used macros like `\chapter` and `\section` to easy the use. I don't know any tool which generates such code, but often there are already programmed packages which extend (La)TeX so that you can call some macro to define special meaning. The quote character for example can be defined using the `newverbs` package. I will add some example code.

Comment: Thanks much for a detailed response. As I understand now that such things are possible in Latex, it is just that we are supposed to write the code for it the way you have written.